# Is it possible to combine vmware-clarity timeline selectors/components to achieve a more complex timeline?

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm a backend developer with basic CSS knowledge. A few days back I found vmware-clarity and I was impressed by their vertical and horizontal timeline designs.

I was wondering if it is possible to combine the [vmware-clarity timeline classes/angular-components](https://clarity.design/documentation/timeline#examples) to achieve something like this

[image]

Basically I need to combine horizontal and vertical timelines but not sure if this is possible using the current CSS classes. Appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is helpful for anyone looking for the same, it is impossible to use the components out of the box and combine them into multiple timelines as in the snippet.

I used multiple vertical timelines, then patch the CSS of the elements to add lines between them, hope this helps.